# I want to create a zabbix alert for sending email to users if no report ran in past 2 hrs

Tags: sql, db2, zabbix

We have zabbix setup in our unix system. And report is connected to DB2 Database where zabbix alert is setup.Now I want to write a query which will invoke this alert when no records is seen in the output.

That means query will check if anything ran in past 2 hr and return those record.If nothing is there as output it will invoke alert.

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp(substr(lastmodifytime,1,19), 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI 
SS'),'GMT') at time zone 'US/Pacific',
objectid, parentid, typeid, ownerID, LastModifyTime
from BODEV.CMS_INFOOBJECTS7 c
where to_date(substr(lastmodifytime,1,19), 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI SS') > 
sysdate - 2/60/60/24
order by lastmodifytime desc;
```

Comment: What are the real values in the `lastmodifytime` column? What's the data type of this column? Can you provide a number of examples?

Comment: 2019 01 22 13 01 18 202
--------This is the format of lastmodifytime column

Comment: LASTMODIFYTIME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)----datatype is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fractional seconds have leading zeroes (i.e. `2019 01 22 13 01 18 002` and not `2019 01 22 13 01 18 2`), then `... where lastmodifytime > to_char(current timestamp - 2 hour, 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI FF3')`.

Use the line with `substr` otherwise.

```
select *
from table(values
  to_char(current timestamp - 3 hour, 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI FF3')
--, to_char(current timestamp - 1 hour, 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI FF3')
) c (lastmodifytime)
where 
lastmodifytime > to_char(current timestamp - 2 hour, 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI FF3')
--substr(lastmodifytime, 1, 19) > to_char(current timestamp - 2 hour, 'YYYY MM DD HH24 MI')
fetch first 1 row only
optimize for 1 row
;
```

Uncomment the 2-nd row to have the result indicating that something ran in past 2 hours.